# update database using AJAX

Tags: mysql, html, sql, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to update my database using AJAX, but somehow it doesn't work. I have already done the part of getting the data from the database into the input fields.

I have an input field "name":

```
<form method="post" ACTION="update.php">
<input maxlength="250" NAME="name" id="name" value="SomeName" SIZE="50">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" id="submit" VALUE="submit">
<span id="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data! Did you fill in all the fields?</span>
<span id="success" style="display:none"> the name has been updated successfully!</span>
</form>
```

And using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#submit").click(function() {

    var name = encodeURIComponent($.trim($("#name").val()));

    var dataString = "name =" + name;

    if(name == "")
    {
        $("#success").fadeOut(2).hide();
        $("#error").fadeOut(200).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
                {
                    if(!data.error)
                    {
                        $("#success").fadeIn(200).show();
                        $("#error").fadeOut(200).hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    return false;

}); 

});
```

I'm passing the name to update.php, which is:

```
<?php  

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'someUsername', 'somePassword');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 mysql_select_db("someDatabase", $con);

 if(isset($_POST['name']))
 {

     $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


     $query="UPDATE SOMETABLE SET name ='$name'";

     $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);

 }

else
{
    echo "Something wrong with the POST";
}


mysql_close($con);
exit;
?>
```

I'm getting the error: "Something wrong with the POST";

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: the problem is not "name" instead of "name =" (which I already have edited). That was just a typing error on here.

Comment: Is name being set from the request/form when you're on the server? Are you stepping through and catching any PHP errors?

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataString = "name" + name;
```

this line should be changed to this;

```
var dataString = "name=" + name;
```

Comment: I will edit my question. I have that already in my code. It's just a typing error here :) So that's not the problem.

Comment: @Nima - You have a space after name in the datastring declaration - "name =" which should be "name="

Comment: did you check what is actually going in the POST request? Possibly from Network tab of Google Chrome inspector

Comment: have php return the $_POST array and post it here

Comment: The array has all the strings I want when I use var_dump. But it also sends the submit button? Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

You use the datatype "json" in the jquery ajax request. And you give only a String to this method.

Change your dataString value to this:

```
var dataString = {'name':name};
```

This should work fine ;)

Comment: The type is supposed to be for the response as far as I remember

Comment: If this works, it may be inferred that you think dataType parameter is to do with what's sent. The dataType parameter is for `"The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."` see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use turn off the option "processData" you need to pass in an object as data.

See this snippet from the jQuery API:

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be passed as an array ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), try changing your post to the following:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
           name: name
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data)
            {
                if(!data.error)
                {
                    $("#success").fadeIn(200).show();
                    $("#error").fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
```